# Filter <p> within a div and wrap all

Tags: javascript, jquery, wrapall

I'm trying to wrap all `<p>` from a `div` in a `sub-div`; the numbers of `<p>` is not constant.

```html
<div id="page">
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
</div>
```

Trying to obtain:

```html
<div id="page">
  <div>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Using:

```
<script>
 jQuery('#page').filter('p').wrapAll('<div></div>');
</script>
```

And it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using [`.wrapAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/) like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/tuqmx/):

```
jQuery('#page p').wrapAll('<div></div>');
```

Or using [`.wrapInner()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/) like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/tuqmx/1/):

```
jQuery('#page').wrapInner('<div></div>');
```

Comment: `wrapAll("<div />")` is also acceptable I believe. Correct me if I'm wrong?

Comment: @Nathan - It is, anything valid in `$(html)` is also valid here, just a bit less readable  IMO :)